# How to create a list/array from an excel, without changing the number type?

Tags: python, excel, list, numpy, xlsx

I'm trying to create a list in order to work the values that I get, but, when I use the

```
nums=pd.read_excel(excel, header=None)
```

and then

```
nums=np.asarray(nums)
```

The type of each value, becomes numpy.float64, so whenever I try to filter a value, based on the fact that it's a float, those values are not counted. Is there a way in which I can create a list/array from a column in excel and the value type doesn't get changed and it's actually read as a regular float? 
(I have tried including the type numpy.float64 in my filter, but the problem is that it includes ints from the excel, which I'm not supposed to use so it does not work)

Any help, thanks!

edit 1:

```
print(nums):
```

```
        0
0    1.00
1    2.00
2    3.00
3    4.00
4    5.00
5    6.00
6    7.00
7    8.00
8    9.00
9   10.00
10   3.30
11   3.22
```

and my expected output would be 1,2,3, etc (int type, instead of numpy.float64 in which they are converted to)

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

edit 2:
If I were to print np.asarray(nums) it'd look like this:

```
 [[ 1.  ]
 [ 2.  ]
 [ 3.  ]
 [ 4.  ]
 [ 5.  ]
 [ 6.  ]
 [ 7.  ]
 [ 8.  ]
 [ 9.  ]
 [10.  ]
 [ 3.3 ]
 [ 3.22]]
```

Comment: Would you please add the output of `print(pd.read_excel(excel, header=None))` and your expected output?

Comment: Check edit 1 :) thanks

Comment: What the original `nums` look like? I'm not asking for `print(np.asarray(nums))`? Do you want to convert `3.30 ` to `3`?

Comment: What I need, is a way to store a number only if it's a float(regular python float, not numpy.float64 or 32, etc), the problem is that python is converting each one of them into numpy.float64, without being able to separate between float and int types. (Check edit 2). If it's not clear yet, my point is that from numbers 1-10, all of them are ints, but as soon as I read them in python, they become: 1.00,2.00,3.00 etc. Or is it a setting from Excel? Because in excel they appear like ints.

Comment: Having a single column with values having different data types on different rows doesn't sound like a very good idea - see below for a solution that allows `numpy` to just use `float64` and still gets you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is more straightforward than what you're suggesting.

Numpy allows you to ask if a float (or float64) is an integer:

```
import numpy as np

a_row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,3.3])
a_column = a_row.reshape(6,1)

print(a_row[4].is_integer())
print(a_row[5].is_integer())
print(a_column[4][0].is_integer())
print(a_column[5][0].is_integer())
```

Result:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), passing the data types you need to the `dtype` argument, e.g.:

`{'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}`

or the `converters` arguments (feed a dict of callables to convert specific values to the types you need).